# Physical meaning of the creation or annihilation operators for a N-electron gases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

For a N-electron gases in a finite volume V, what is the meaning of the first "=" in the following expression:
$$a({\bf{x}})^\dagger=a(|{\bf{x}}\rangle)^\dagger=a(\sum_{\bf{k}}|v_{\bf{k}}\rangle\langle{v_{\bf{k}}}|{\bf{x}}\rangle)^\dagger=\frac{1}{L^{3/2}}\sum_{\bf{k}}e^{-i{\bf{k}}\cdot{\bf{x}}}a_{\bf{k}}^\dagger.$$

($|v_\bf{k}(\bf{x})\rangle$ is a basis vector in the occupation number representation, and $$v_{\bf{k}}({\bf{x}})=\langle{{\bf{x}}|v_\bf{k}}\rangle=\frac{1}{L^{3/2}}\sum_{\bf{k}}e^{i{\bf{k}}\cdot{\bf{x}}}.$$

Comment: Your first equation does not seem to make sense, and I don't see your function $v_k(x)$ in it.

Comment: @Adam because in the first equation, in the second step one can insert the $$\sum_{\bf{k}}|v_{\bf{k}}\rangle\langle{v_{\bf{k}}}|$$,and get $$a(\sum_{\bf{k}}|v_{\bf{k}}\rangle\langle{v_{\bf{k}}}|x)^\dagger$$then use the expression of $|v_{\bf{k}}\rangle$.

Comment: Your notations are confusing: $a(|x\langle)^\dagger$ i clearly not standard, and may not make sense at all.

Comment: @Adam I think so. because ${\bf{x}}$ is a parameter, not a state.

Comment: Then, what is the difference between $a(x)^\dagger$ (which is the standard notation for a creation operator with parameter $x$) and $a(|x\rangle)^\dagger$ ?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once you are satisfied. If you feel the answers are not sufficient, you can always ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the formulae you have written I think this is what's going on:

$\left| x \rangle \right.$ is a state of the system in which there is one excitation at point $x$ and everything else is in the ground state. $a(\left| x \rangle \right.)$ is the operator that removes one excitation at point $x$. In other words
$$a(\left| x \rangle \right.)\left| x \rangle \right.=\left| 0 \rangle \right.$$
where $\left| 0 \rangle \right.$ is the ground state of the system. $a(x)$ is just a short hand notation for $a(\left| x \rangle \right.)$, and actually $a(x)$ is much more standard in my experience.

$\left| v_k \rangle \right.$ is a plane wave state. $v_k(x) \equiv \langle x|v_k \rangle$ is the value of the wave function for the $\left| v_k \rangle \right.$ state in the position basis, evaluated at point $x$. Note that the symbol $()$ is being used in two different ways, which is probably the source of the confusion.